# Generating Clusplot for K Prototype in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have a customer dataset with a mix continuous and categorical variables, and would like to do cluster the customers into groups. Am trying to use k prototype for the first time, but how would I get a nice, visual representation similar to cusplot for kmeans?

```
install.packages("clustMixType")
library(clustMixType)
data = read.csv("customerdata.csv", header = TRUE)
kproto = kproto(data, k=5, lambda = NULL, iter.max = 100, nstart = 1,
   keep.data = TRUE)
clprofiles(kproto, data, vars = NULL, col = NULL)
```

Comment: This depends a lot on your data. If you have two or more (continuous) numerical variables, you could do the same thing that clusplot does - plot the data using the first two principal components. If you have all categorical data, any plotting can be difficult.

Comment: I have around 5 of each type of variable. Do I just use cusplot in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Don't rely on a black box function.

Study what clusplot does, and adapt it to suit your needs exactly. Get the source code, and check what it does.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in your code where `krpoto` is the object and `data` as the data frame

```
clprofiles(kproto, data, vars = NULL, col = NULL)
```